# Difference between main and main()

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

The following code 1 is fine

```
#include <stdio.h>    // code 1
main()
{
    printf("%u",main);
}
```

but this code 2 gives segmentation fault.

```
#include <stdio.h>  // code 2
main()
{
    printf("%u",main());
}
```

I'm not getting what's the difference between main and main()?

Comment: It's amazing that you found this site, as its name is so relevant to your question...

Comment: That's because 'main' is the technically the address of the function, while main() is the function call. Though I have to ask: What's the return type of that main of yours? void? The segfault is actually, because you're causing an infinite loop there...you call main, which calls main, which calls main...at some point, your stack is full and you get: Who guessed it: A stack overflow! (Disguised as segmentation fault)

Comment: @ATaylor: the return type is `int`, because that's the default in C when not otherwise specified.

Comment: Both pieces of code are wrong.  The only difference is why.

Comment: @GregHewgill That's what I thought, but shouldn't his compiler scream out for not including a return statement then?

Comment: @ATaylor: yeah, for now it's void.

Comment: @ATaylor: Probably, but C compilers are notoriously lax on that point.

Comment: @GregHewgill: `int` is the default in C89/C90. In C99, declaring a function with no return type is a constraint violation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you compile with all warnings enabled from your compiler? With `gcc` that means giving the `-Wall` argument to `gcc` (and `-g` is useful for debugging info).

First, your `printf("%u", main)` should be `printf("%p\n", main)`. The `%p` prints a pointer (technically function pointers are not data pointers as needed for `%p`, practically they often have the same size and similar representation), and you should end your format strings with newline `\n`. This takes the *address* of the `main` function and passes that address to `printf`.

Then, your second `printf("%u", main())` is calling `printf` with an argument obtained by a [recursive call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29) to the `main` function. This recursion never ends, and you blow up your call stack (i.e. have a stack overflow), so get a `SIGSEGV` on Unix.

Pedantically, `main` is a very special name for *C* standard, and you probably should not call it (it is called auto-magically by startup code in `crt0.o`). Recursing on `main` is very bad taste and may be illegal.

See also my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11698515/841108).

Comment: No, I just compiled it as gcc file.c and also are we allowed to call other functions than main()?

Comment: You should *always* enable warnings. Of course you are allowed to call functions, and you do call `printf`.

Comment: That's incorrect, you can call main in C (but not in C++). Not returning from main isn't a problem either, it's equivalent to returning 0/calling exit(0).

Comment: Please show the standard phrase allowing call to `main`. I remember having read something which allows the compiler to produce a non-function for it (even if most implementations do compile it to a function).

Comment: No, `printf("%p\n", main)` has undefined behavior. `%p` requires a `void*` argument; `main` (after decay) is a function pointer. It's possible for function pointers to have an entirely different representation than `void*`.

Comment: `main` is a function. §5.1.2.2.1/1: "The function called at program startup is named `main`." C++ says that: "main shall not be used within a program" (§3.6.1/3), but the C standard doesn't say anything of the sort.

Comment: [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 6.5.2.2p11: "Recursive function calls shall be permitted, both directly and indirectly through any chain of other functions." No exception to this rule is stated for `main`. (C++ forbids recursive calls to `main`.)