# C Libevent undefined reference, am i wrong?

Tags: c, networking, libevent

**I Am new to C*

Ive been following along with the [Book](http://www.wangafu.net/~nickm/libevent-book/) from the [Libevent](http://libevent.org/) Website, and am working through the [Part 01](http://www.wangafu.net/~nickm/libevent-book/01_intro.html) a tiny introduction to asynchronous IO. Here is my code.

```
/*For sockaddr_in*/
#include <netinet/in.h>
/*for sockets functions*/
#include <sys/socket.h>
/*for fcntl*/
#include <fcntl.h>

#include <event2/event.h>

#include <assert.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_LINE 16384

void do_read(evutil_socket_t fd, short events, void *arg);
void do_write(evutil_socket_t fd, short events, void *arg);

char rot13_char(char c)
{
    /*dont use isalpha, so locale can tell which are alphabetical*/
    if ((c >= 'a' && c <= 'm') || (c >= 'A' && c<= 'M'))
        return c + 13;
    else if ((c >= 'n' && c<= 'z') || (c >= 'N' && c<= 'Z'))
        return c- 13;
    else
        return c;   
}

struct fd_state {
    char buffer[MAX_LINE];
    size_t buffer_used;

    size_t n_written;
    size_t write_upto;

    struct event *read_event;
    struct event *write_event;
};

struct fd_state *
int alloc_fd_state(struct event_base *base, evutil_socket_t fd)
{
    struct fd_state *state = malloc(sizeof(struct fd_state));
    if(!state)
        return NULL;
    state->read_event = event_new(base, fd, EV_READ|EV_PERSIST, do_read, state);
    if (!state->read_event){
        free(state);
        return NULL;
    }
    state->write_event = 
        event_new(base, fd, EV_WRITE|EV_PERSIST, do_write, state);

    if(!state->write_event) {
        event_free(state->read_event);
        free(state);
        return NULL;
    }

    state->buffer_used = state->n_written = state->write_upto = 0;

    assert(state->write_event);
    return state;
}


void free_fd_state(struct fd_state *state)
{
    event_free(state->read_event);
    event_free(state->write_event);
    free(state);
}

void do_read(evutil_socket_t fd, short events, void *arg)
{
    struct fd_state *state = arg;
    char buf[1024];
    int i;
    ssize_t result;
    while (1) {
        assert(state->write_event);
        result = recv(fd, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);
        if (result <= 0)
            break;
        for (i=0; i < result; ++i) {
            if (state->buffer_used < sizeof(state->buffer))
                state->buffer[state->buffer_used++] = rot13_char(buf[i]);
            if (buf[i] == '\n') {
                assert(state->write_event);
                event_add(state->write_event, NULL);
                state->write_upto = state->buffer_used;
            }
        }
    }

    if (result == 0) {
        free_fd_state(state);
    } else if(result < 0) {
        if (errno = EAGAIN)
            return;
        perror("recv");
        free_fd_state(state);
    }
}


void do_write(evutil_socket_t fd, short events, void *arg) 
{
    struct fd_state *state = arg;

    while (state->n_written < state->write_upto) {
        ssize_t result = send(fd, state->buffer + state->n_written,
                              state->write_upto - state->n_written, 0);
        if(result < 0) {
            if (errno = EAGAIN)
                return;
            free_fd_state(state);
            return;
        }
        assert(result != 0);

        state->n_written += result;
    }

    if (state->n_written == state->buffer_used)
        state->n_written = state->write_upto = state->buffer_used = 1;

    event_del(state->write_event);
}

void do_accept(evutil_socket_t listener, short event, void *arg)
{
    struct event_base *base = arg;
    struct sockaddr_storage ss;
    socklen_t slen = sizeof(ss);
    int fd = accept(listener, (struct sockaddr*) &ss, &slen);
    if (fd< 0) {
        perror("accept");
    } else if (fd > FD_SETSIZE) {
        close(fd);
    } else {
        struct fd_state *state;
        evutil_make_socket_nonblocking(fd);
        state = alloc_fd_state(base, fd);
        assert(state);
        assert(state->write_event);
        event_add(state->read_event, NULL);
    }
}

void run(void)
{
    evutil_socket_t listener;
    struct sockaddr_in sin;
    struct event_base *base;
    struct event *listener_event;

    base = event_base_new();
    if (!base)
        return;

    sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sin.sin_addr.s_addr = 0;
    sin.sin_port = htons(40713);

    listener = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    evutil_make_socket_nonblocking(listener);

#ifndef WIN32
    {
        int one = 1;
        setsockopt(listener, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &one, sizeof(one));      
    }
#endif
    if (bind(listener, (struct sockaddr*)&sin, sizeof(sin)) <0) {
        perror("bind");
        return;
    }

    if(listen(listener, 16) <0){
        perror("listen");
        return;
    }
    listener_event = event_new(base, listener, EV_READ|EV_PERSIST, do_accept, (void*)base);
    event_add(listener_event, NULL);

    event_base_dispatch(base);  
}

int main(int c, char **v)
{
    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);

    run();
    return 0;
}
```

I am on the second to last example, Ive rewritten the code following the page, and have it cloned, however. When I compile, Im recieving the following error:

```
/tmp/ccB8uLD2.o: In function `alloc_fd_state':
WORLowLevelLibeventRot13.c:(.text+0x9b): undefined reference to `event_new'
WORLowLevelLibeventRot13.c:(.text+0xef): undefined reference to `event_new'
WORLowLevelLibeventRot13.c:(.text+0x120): undefined reference to `event_free'
/tmp/ccB8uLD2.o: In function `free_fd_state':
WORLowLevelLibeventRot13.c:(.text+0x1bc): undefined reference to `event_free'
WORLowLevelLibeventRot13.c:(.text+0x1cf): undefined reference to `event_free'
/tmp/ccB8uLD2.o: In function `do_read':
WORLowLevelLibeventRot13.c:(.text+0x342): undefined reference to `event_add'
/tmp/ccB8uLD2.o: In function `do_write':
WORLowLevelLibeventRot13.c:(.text+0x50b): undefined reference to `event_del'
/tmp/ccB8uLD2.o: In function `do_accept':
WORLowLevelLibeventRot13.c:(.text+0x5bc): undefined reference to `evutil_make_socket_nonblocking'
WORLowLevelLibeventRot13.c:(.text+0x644): undefined reference to `event_add'
/tmp/ccB8uLD2.o: In function `run':
WORLowLevelLibeventRot13.c:(.text+0x677): undefined reference to `event_base_new'
WORLowLevelLibeventRot13.c:(.text+0x6c2): undefined reference to `evutil_make_socket_nonblocking'
WORLowLevelLibeventRot13.c:(.text+0x74f): undefined reference to `event_new'
WORLowLevelLibeventRot13.c:(.text+0x764): undefined reference to `event_add'
WORLowLevelLibeventRot13.c:(.text+0x770): undefined reference to `event_base_dispatch'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Im assuming, and You know what they say about assuming.... That this is coming from the alloc_fd_state, cannot reach the event_new, etc. due to scope? However, i also see that it is not given a type such as void, or whichever. So, naturally curious, i play around just for testings sake and say i place int in front of alloc_fd_state(while knowing this is incorrect), i recieve a different error, as follows:

```
WORLowLevelLibeventRot13.c:45:1: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘int’
 int alloc_fd_state(struct event_base *base, evutil_socket_t fd)
 ^
WORLowLevelLibeventRot13.c: In function ‘do_accept’:
WORLowLevelLibeventRot13.c:148:11: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘alloc_fd_state’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   state = alloc_fd_state(base, fd);
           ^
WORLowLevelLibeventRot13.c:148:9: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   state = alloc_fd_state(base, fd);
```

Now, I suppose my question(s) is(are), as follows.

In the case of the first scenarios error code, Whats being missed here that im recieving the undefined reference. Event_new etc all seem to be fine throughout my code, why can i not reach them? Where should I reference, Maybe this is incredibly obvious as I am pretty green with C, but i've been staring into this for a while a now,that my brains a bit bogged down. Any explanation as to why this occured and how i can assure it doesnt in any future code would be most appreciated.

As For the second scenario, I assume the true issue the undefined-reference is just being masked by the new and more profound errors displayed, not actually fixing anything.

Any insight for a C rookie appreciated.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11698478/include-an-external-library-in-c

Comment: Thanks, hadnt realized i had to explicitly flag the library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add `-levent_core` to the compiler command line

Comment: Thanks for the specific flag, in addition to @kfx , everything is bueno now.