# Make a makefile for cjson code with -lcjson for json parser in c

Tags: c, makefile, cjson

I'm very new to the makefiles. I'm compiling the c code file which contains cJson library from terminal using command

```
gcc -test1.c -o test -lcjson
```

with -lcjson at last and its running perfectly. But how to compile the same code using makefile as I have to add -lcjson at last.
if I'm using without -lcjson I'm getting error

```
/tmp/cc4ESrx1.o: In function `parse_json':
test1.c:(.text+0x2d): undefined reference to `cJSON_Parse'
test1.c:(.text+0x42): undefined reference to `cJSON_GetObjectItem'
test1.c:(.text+0x59): undefined reference to `cJSON_GetObjectItem'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm using a RTOS code

thanks in advance

Comment: I believe your question is why you are getting undefined, you might want to review sequence of specifying the lib, also -test1.c should be -c test1.c

Comment: @Pras: No, `-c` is needed to get an object file. When compiling a single source file into an executable it should *not* be used.

Comment: @Aditya: your are *not* compiling the C code of the `-lcjson` library. You are just *linking* and using that library.

Answer (score -1):

First, avoid naming your executable `test` since it is a standard program name (at least on POSIX).

Then, read [documentation of GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html). It contains a tutorial section.

At last, GNU make has several built-in rules, which you can get with `make -p`

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16751650/841108) for an example.

I strongly recommend compiling with all warnings and debug info (that is, with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)). So put `CFLAGS+= -Wall -Wextra -g` and `CC=gcc` in your `Makefile`.

To link with your `-lcjson`  add `LIBES+= -lcjson` in your `Makefile`. Remember that <kbd>tab</kbd> characters are important in a `Makefile` (so use some editor, e.g. `emacs`, able to edit them).

So try:

```
# your Makefile, replace four spaces with tab
CC= gcc
CFLAGS+= -Wall -Wextra -g
RM= rm -f
MY_SOURCES=$(wildcard *.c)
## above could be an MY_SOURCES= file1.c file2.c otherfile.c
MY_OBJECTS=$(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(MY_SOURCES))
# 
LIBES= -lcjson
#
.PHONY: all clean
##
all: myprog
## 
clean:
     $(RM) myprog *.o *~
myprog: $(MY_OBJECTS)
```

Use `make --trace` or [`remake`](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/) `-x` to debug your `Makefile`

If you haver *several* `*.c` source files (that is [translation units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming))) linked together into the same program, you should have a common header file `myheader.h` (to share common declarations of all your public functions and variables) which should be `#include`-ed in every source file. Then you need to depend on it:

```
 MY_HEADER= myheader.h
 %.o: %.c $(MY_HEADER)
```

Notice that (with or without any `Makefile`) the order of [program arguments to `gcc`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) is very *significant*. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11698515/841108).