# How to compile with headers and a create a Makefile - C

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, compilation, header

I am trying to compile and create a Makefile with my source code organized as per the following structure:

```
|-- build
|-- include
| \-- functions.h
\-- src
|-- functions.c
\-- main.c
```

The code written there has been tested on an IDE, so I know it works. I just need to compile it but I don't know how to execute 2 files with extensions .c and the .h file. ALSO, I need to create a makefile for this.

How?

Comment: [Reading this](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) might help you get started.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a do-my-homework service, but you should use it to learn things and ask questions with some [MCVE]

Comment: Try something simpler first, like `HelloWorld` without a makefile.

Answer (score 1):

A `Makefile` is just some textual file (where <kbd>tab</kbd> characters are *significant* at least when they start a command line). Use some [source code editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code_editor) to create or improve it; I prefer [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) so recommend it, but you could use some other editor (e.g. [vim](http://vim.org/), `gedit`, etc...), it is a matter of taste. BTW, don't forget to use some version control system (I recommend [git](http://git-scm.com/)).

Before creating your `Makefile` take some time to read the [documentation of `make`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html). Be aware of the numerous built-in rules (which you could obtain by running `make -p`) and take advantage of them.

> how to execute 2 .c files and the .h file.

You don't *execute* `.c` files, but you feed them to your C [compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler). I recommend using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) (or perhaps [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/)) as your C compiler.

You probably should set the `CC`  make variable (it gives the default C compiler) to `gcc`, and the `CFLAGS` variable (it gives default compiler flags).

So read documentation about [Invoking GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html). You surely want to compile with all warnings and debug info.

Hence, I recommend to have the following two lines in your `Makefile`

```
 CC= gcc
 CFLAGS= -Wall -Wextra -g
```

Of course, you need other lines in your `Makefile`. I leave you to read more and experiment. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16751650/841108) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44426536/841108) should be inspirational.

You probably want to mention the dependency on your header file(s) in your `Makefile`.

So I leave you to **write *your* [`Makefile`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile)**. Consider it as [source code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code), so backup and version control it carefully.

BTW, for a tiny program like yours, I don't think that having `src/` and  `include/`  directories is useful, and I believe that introducing a `build/`  directory is just adding unnecessary complexity. YMMV.

> The code written there has been tested on a IDE, so I know it works.

This could be an illusion. Sometimes you can have the bad luck of having some [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) which simply "appears" to work but is a bug. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108) and follow the links I gave there.

There are many [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) projects built with `make`; look on [github](http://github.com/) and elsewhere to find some. Sometimes `Makefile`s are themselves generated (e.g. using [cmake](http://cmake.org/), [qmake](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-manual.html), or [autoconf](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/index.html)), but that is not worthwhile in your simple case.

<sup>PS. Don't expect StackOverflow to do your homework.</sup>