# C - makefile error undefined reference to main

Tags: c, makefile

```
    dealer: dealer.o readline.o car.o
        gcc -o dealer readline.o car.o

    dealer.o: dealer.c car.h readline.h
        gcc -c dealer.c

    readline.o: readline.c car.h readline.h
        gcc -c readline.c

    car.o: car.c car.h readline.h
        gcc -c car.c

make dealer
gcc -c dealer.c
gcc -c readline.c
gcc -c car.c
gcc -o dealer readline.o car.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../lib64/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [dealer] Error 1
```

I keep getting the error above. My dealer.c does indeed contain 'main'.

Does anybody have an idea on whats going on?

Comment: Pass `-Wall -g` to `gcc`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44426536/841108)

Comment: I suspect `dealer.o` is probably supposed to be one of the object files linked into your `dealer` binary.  Edit: oh, I didn't notice it was already covered in the answers.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I will take a look at it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your link line:

```
gcc -o dealer readline.o car.o
```

doesn't contain `dealer.o`, which explains why `main` is missing. Should be:

```
gcc -o dealer dealer.o readline.o car.o
```

(there's no automatic/guessed relation between the name of the final executable indicated by `-o dealer` and the object file `dealer.o`)

Comment: That was it! Thank you!! edit: Thanks for your edit explaining things.